# An internal error occurred during: "reload maven project"

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project which is under development. It was working till yesterday and it started throwing me the below error in eclipse whenever I click on something in the editor/saving the file. Seems Maven is not be able to recognize in eclipse.

I have checked the maven settings and set the maven home path in eclipse.

[Click here to see the ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA0H1.png)

I tried with new eclipse and also switching the workspace. Removed the .metadata from the workspace. But no luck.

Comment: By removing the `.metadata` folder you removed all your preferences and much more. What's changed since yesterday (`pom.xml`, Java version, Eclipse version, additional plug-ins, etc.)? Please show the full error message from the log as text and also add the `pom.xml` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response @howlger!

Nothing has been changed/updated. All are working earlier and it happened suddenly. I hope it was crashed. 

I downloaded a new eclipse and and created a new workspace for it. It resolved the issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it